# Request response pattern in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I was wondering what's the proper way to handle requests/responses in Redux.

#### Our current setup is this :

1. Components are obviously connected to Redux and can dispatch actions.
2. A saga listens to specific actions, and performs a web socket request.
3. A different saga listens to incoming websocket messages and updates the store with the incoming data.(by dispatching it's own actions)

This has worked pretty well, except for a specific use case of knowing the exact moment a specific response has arrived.

This is especially problematic as some requests don't return any meaningful data, they just return status that the operation succeeded.

#### We're currently discussing two solutions :

1. Send callback with the action from the dispatching component, on response trigger the callback, this feels very anti-pattern to redux.
2. Maintain a state in the store of all outgoing requests, allow the dispatching component to provide a UUID for the specific action so that this component can then query the store to see if the response arrived, it's also needed to reset of the incoming responses or maintain the state in the component that this specific response was resolved. In any case, a lot of overhead and potential bugs.

The usual use case is opening a popup the moment a response arrived.

Answer (score 0):

I used promise with callbacks and chaining different requests needed inside the completion of request.
This [Medium](https://medium.com/react-native-training/redux-4-ways-95a130da0cdc) article helped me out. It deals with implementation of **Think** vs **Saga** vs **Observable** vs **Redux promise middleware**.
Haven't tried saga yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you reached the point where you need a better state management. Remember that Redux is about storing the data and data flow. It is not exactly about state management. I’ll suggest to read about state machines. I can recognize the different states of your requests and they could easily managed using state machine. Here’s a write up on the topic http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/managing-state-in-javascript-with-state-machines-stent